# Equality between encrypted hash of data and hash of encrypted data?

Tags: encryption, hash

Are there any cryptographically strong hash function and encryption function(s) where `hash(encryptA(data)) == encryptB(hash(data))`.  The functions `encryptA()` and `encryptB()` may be identical, or just related.

If no such functions currently exist, are there theoretical reasons (relating to the one-way nature of hash functions) why they cannot exist?

Comment: So, basically you are asking are there two permutation that a permutation before hash equal to another permutation after hash. We hope not such simple relation exist in cryptographically secure hash functions.

Comment: Thanks, that shows why it would not be a good hash function.  Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108282/reorderable-encryptions

Answer (score 1):

I'll show a strange result under some assumptions.

Consider the simplified notation;

$$H(E(d,k_1)) = E(H(d),k_2) \label{r1}\tag{1}$$

and for simplicity, **assume the hash output is 128-bit**.

Now, consider that one finds two 128-bit inputs $a \neq b$ such that $H(a) = H(b)$, i.e. we have a colliding pair.

The right-hand side of eqn. (\ref{r1}) with the input $a$ and $b$. Then

$$E(H(a),k_2) = E(H(b),k_2) \label{r2}\tag{2}$$

since $a$ and $b$ is a collision. Now consider the left side;

$$H(E(a,k_1)) = H(E(b,k_1)) \label{r3}\tag{3}$$ This equality holds since the right sides are equal.

Now, for this equality, either

- $E(a,k_1) = E(b,k_1) $
  This is not possible since $a \neq b$
- then we may have $E(a,k_1) \neq E(b,k_1) $
  I.e. we have very unlucky that $E(a,k_1) = b$ and $E(b,k_1) = a$.

  If we do not consider that unlucky case ($\dfrac{1}{2^{128}}$ probability), than **we have another colliding pair**!

Now, **use them again to get another pair**, the use them **another pair...**

Where this will stop, I have no idea, however, we may consider that **the best solution** for our secure cryptographic hash function is this;

- **The encryptions are identity maps**.

---

Well, one may consider the output size of the hash functions as 256 or more, with ECB mode encryption or others. This may require a different analysis, that I will not consider, however, we showed that this requirement is not good for secure cryptographic hash functions.