# Reorderable encryptions

Tags: encryption

Are there any two encryption function(s) where `encryptB(encryptA(data, keyA), keyB) == encryptA(encryptB(data, keyB), keyA)`.

The two functions may be related or identical.

The two keys must be distinct and unrelated.

Comment: Many classical ciphers, stream ciphers, AES-CTR...